# PHP, XAMPP, Sql Server

Tags: php, xampp, microsoft-azure, sql-server-2014

Boa noite galera,

Estou tentando conectar o php com sql server já tem uns dois dias, alguem pode me ajudar ?

Ele só mostra isso :
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexaoSqlServer\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexaoSqlServer\index.php on line 5

Estou usando windows 10, php 7.2.1, xampp 3.2.2, Sql Server 2014 Express

Instalei o drive : php para sql server :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

dentro da pasta xampp/php/ext

Colei no php.ini as linhas:
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll

E mesmo assim não foi... tenho 2 sql server 1 no Azure e outro Local, tentei nos dois e não rolou

Meu código php está assim

$serverName = "db-luciano.database.windows.net";

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"DB_BANCO_DE_HORAS","UID"=>"usuario","PWD"=>"senha");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if($conn) {

```
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
```

}else{

```
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

}

Conectando no local, o serverName -> coloquei localhost, e também tentei com o nome do servidor que peguei com o comando select @@servername

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMZHB.png)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se vc tem o php 7.2 precisa usar as dll da versão 7.2 e não do 7.1

Answer (score 0):

Saudações! Ficou um pouco estranho sua pergunta, mas vou te responder pelo que eu consegui entender. Aparentemente você está tentando fazer uma conexão de PHP no banco de dados através do seu Apache no XAMPP.

Para isto, você não precisa instalar o MySQL Server por fora, o próprio XAMPP já inclui o servidor de MySQL nele mesmo, como você pode ver abaixo. Basta iniciar o módulo.

[image: Print do MySQL no XAMPP]

E para você fazer conexões via PHP no Banco de dados, recomendo que você utilize o PDO. Você pode saber mais sobre criar scripts utilizando o PDO neste link: https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-php-pdo/24973

Espero ter sido útil para ti.

Comment: Então Arthur , com o MySql é bemmm tranquilo, eu preciso conectar no SqlServer...